# Window object not recognized

Tags: html, node.js

I am trying to make a server (`node`) communicate with an `html` webpage. Everything, worked for both sides, but since I tried to link both sides, I got the following quite inconvenient error :

```
/home/gaga/js/index.js
window.onload = setTimeout(mainFile.start, 1);
^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Here is index.js:

```
var Message={};
var serv = "localhost:1337";

Message.start = function () {
    document.addEventListener("click", Message.click);
    document.addEventListener("change", Message.onChange);
    Message.getStatus();
};

Message.click = function (ev) {
    var src = ev.target;

    if (src.has_class("navbar-brand")) {
        window.location.reload();
    } else if (src.has_class("btn-confirm-registration")) {
        Message.register();
    } else if (src.has_class("btn-register")) {
        Message.confirmRegistrationInputDisplay();
    } else if (src.has_class("btn-login")) {
        Message.login();
    } else if (src.has_class("btn-send-file")) {
        Message.sendFile();
    } else if (src.has_class("btn-success")) {
        Message.cleanUploadInfo();
    } else if (src.has_class("btn-failure")) {
        Message.cleanUploadInfo();
    } else {
        console.log("else");
    }
};

Message.onChange = function (ev) {
    var src = ev.target;

    if(src.has_class("input-upload")) {
        Message.displayInputFile(src);
    } else {
        console.log("onChange-else");
    }

}

Message.register = function () {
    var logIn = document.getElementsByClassName("login-input")[0];
    var pswIn = document.getElementsByClassName("password-input")[0];

    if (pswIn.value != "" && logIn.value != "") {
        logIn.remove_class("alert-danger");
        pswIn.remove_class("alert-danger");

        var registrationModule = document.getElementsByClassName("confirm-registration")[0];
        registrationModule.innerHTML = "<input type=\"password\" class=\"input confirm-password-input form-control\" style=\"width: 150px; display: inline; margin-left: 160px;\" placeholder=\"Confirm password...\"></input><button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-confirm-    registration\">Confirm Registration</input>";
    } else {
        logIn.add_class("alert-danger");
        pswIn.add_class("alert-danger");
    }
}

Message.checkPasswords = function () {
    var logIn = document.getElementsByClassName("login-input")[0];
    var pswIn = document.getElementsByClassName("password-input")[0];
    var pswConf = document.getElementsByClassName("confirm-password-input")[0];

    if (pswIn.value == pswConf.value && pswIn.value != "" && logIn.value != "") {
        pswConf.remove_class("alert-danger");
        pswIn.remove_class("alert-danger");
        logIn.value = "";
        pswIn.value = "";
        return 1;
    } else {
        pswConf.add_class("alert-danger");
        pswIn.add_class("alert-danger");
        return 0;
    }
}

Message.login = function () {
    var logIn = document.getElementsByClassName("login-input")[0];
    var pswIn = document.getElementsByClassName("password-input")[0];

    if (pswIn.value != "" && logIn.value != "") {
        logIn.remove_class("alert-danger");
        pswIn.remove_class("alert-danger");
        //here send request
        logIn.value = "";
        pswIn.value = "";
    } else {
        logIn.add_class("alert-danger");
        pswIn.add_class("alert-danger");
    }
}

Message.sendFile = function () {//todo: arnaud
    var sendFile = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-input")[0];

    if (sendFile.value != "") {
        sendFile.remove_class("alert-danger");
        var data = serv + "?fileName=" + sendFile.value;
        Message.post(data, Message.cb_sendFile);
    } else {
        sendFile.add_class("alert-danger");
    }
}

Message.cb_sendFile = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName("upload-info")[0];
        if (resp.status == "ok") {
            el.innerHTML = "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"> Success</button>";
        } else {
            el.innerHTML = "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"> Failure</button>";
        }
    }
}

Message.displayInputFile = function (src) {
    var file = src.value;
    var fileInput = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-input")[0];
    fileInput.remove_class("alert-danger");
    fileInput.value = file.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
}

Message.getStatus = function () {
    console.log("do nothing");
}

window.onload = setTimeout(Message.start, 1);
```

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <title>aboudabi</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"></link>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">aboudabi</a>
                </div>

                <div class="login-registration-input">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user-status">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="row col-lg-12">
            <div class="file-input col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1">
                <input class="form-control doc-input" style="width: 400px; display: inline;" placeholder="Your file..."></input>
                <div class="file-upload btn btn-default">
                    <span>Browse</span>
                    <input class="upload input-upload" type="file"/>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-upload btn-send-file"> Send</button>
                <br>
                <div class="upload-info col-lg-6">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="confirm-registration col-lg-5">
            </div>          
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't showing your node code here... It sounds like you executed `index.js` on the server, using something like `require('index.js')`. If so, you need to serve the file with `express.static` or `res.sendFile` or some such similar approach.

Comment: Thank you. I do not understand when you say: serve the file...

Comment: To explain everything I think you need to know, I'd have to go into a lot of details about various subjects. I think it would be best for you just to work on a hello world node app, then a hello world app with express and make sure you understand what's going on.

Comment: Ok. Any example of such app that would fit my needs?

Comment: I just went ahead and wrote some examples that should help you. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be having trouble understanding how to setup your node server, I'll demonstrate the most basic setup and add another layer of complexity in each example from there.

```
/** Make a server that responds to all requests with index.html **/

var http = require('http');
var fs   = require('fs'); // interact with file system

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  // this is how the server will respond to requests
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res); // read the file and pipe it to the response
}).listen(80);


/** serve index.html for `/` or x.html for `/x` **/

var http = require('http');
var fs   = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var file = req.url.split('/')[1] || 'index'; // get the first word from the url
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream(file+'.html');
  readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    // file doesn't exist
    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end("This page doesn't exist."); // simple text error message as response
  });
  readStream.pipe(res);
}).listen(80);
```

As you can see, you have to write code to give meaning to a request. If a request comes into the server for `/js/myFile.js`, then in some way, the server has to think something like this:

```
if (req.url === '/js/myFile.js') {
   var readStream = fs.createReadSteam('/js/myFile.js');
   // set headers, handle errors and such, then
   readStream.pipe(res);
 }
```

Of course, you would write code that can handle this more generically, so that you don't repeat the same code over and over again, and of course, someone has already written just the code you need. [**Express**](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html) has a router and  static file server built in. It makes the above process much nicer.

```
var express    = require('express');
var app = express();

// serve all files in `js` folder
app.use(express.static('/js'));

// respond with `index.html` for all other requests
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.listen(80);
```